# How to run Selenium test suite on jenkins simultaneously

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-grid

Right now I made 5 test suites on selenium IDE. So, for each one I make a new Jenkins Job. Each one of these suites last about 30 minutes, but I need to run the 5 test suites at time to save time. I read about Selenium Grid plugin but it isn't working for me because it starts a selenium-server.jar automatically and the build cannot run for it, because it cannot start another selenium-server.jar...So I want to know if there is another option or if I have to wait for each suite to finish to run the another one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to run multiple suites at the same time. Just start their selenium jar with a different port:

```
java -jar ${JAR_FILE} -port ${PORT} -htmlSuite *firefox ${BASE_URL} ${SUITE_FILE}
```

You can also look into SeleniumHQ for jenkins: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Seleniumhq+Plugin

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using that plugin and that it's how I run the testsuites but I need to run lots of Suites at time

Comment: I choose this as the correct answer because in Jenkins I just have to add the option "-port xxxx" and it worked. Thanks.